# uninitialized constant ActionDispatch (NameError) in Ruby

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

My Code in ruby class is. Here i am getting uninitialized constant ActionDispatch (NameError)

```
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
    # Make the Capybara DSL available in all integration tests
    include Capybara::DSL

    # Stop ActiveRecord from wrapping tests in transactions
    self.use_transactional_fixtures = false

    teardown do
        DatabaseCleaner.clean       # Truncate the database
        Capybara.reset_sessions!    # Forget the (simulated) browser state
        Capybara.use_default_driver 
    end
end
```

Comment: where is this code? what version of rails?

Comment: I am writing this is for cucumber test cases. It is in test_helper.rb
I am using Rails 3.1.0

Comment: Maybe paste your whole test_helper.rb. You didn't replace all the code in it with the above did you?

Comment: I have taken the reference from https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, after upgrading.

This is my stack trace:

```
uninitialized constant ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest (NameError)
/Users/etagwerker/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@ombu/gems/cucumber-rails-1.3.1/lib/cucumber/rails/world.rb:9:in `<module:Rails>'
/Users/etagwerker/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@ombu/gems/cucumber-rails-1.3.1/lib/cucumber/rails/world.rb:8:in `<module:Cucumber>'
/Users/etagwerker/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@ombu/gems/cucumber-rails-1.3.1/lib/cucumber/rails/world.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/etagwerker/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@ombu/gems/backports-3.3.0/lib/backports/tools.rb:328:in `require'
/Users/etagwerker/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@ombu/gems/backports-3.3.0/lib/backports/tools.rb:328:in `require_with_backports'
/Users/etagwerker/Projects/om/features/support/env.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/etagwerker/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@ombu/gems/cucumber-1.3.1/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:122:in `load'
/Users/etagwerker/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@ombu/gems/cucumber-1.3.1/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:122:in `load_code_file'
/Users/etagwerker/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@ombu/gems/cucumber-1.3.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:180:in `load_file'
/Users/etagwerker/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@ombu/gems/cucumber-1.3.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `block in load_files!'
/Users/etagwerker/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@ombu/gems/cucumber-1.3.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
/Users/etagwerker/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@ombu/gems/cucumber-1.3.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
/Users/etagwerker/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@ombu/gems/cucumber-1.3.1/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:183:in `load_step_definitions'
/Users/etagwerker/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@ombu/gems/cucumber-1.3.1/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:42:in `run!'
/Users/etagwerker/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@ombu/gems/cucumber-1.3.1/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:47:in `execute!'
/Users/etagwerker/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@ombu/gems/cucumber-1.3.1/bin/cucumber:13:in `<top (required)>'
script/cucumber:9:in `load'
script/cucumber:9:in `<main>'
```

I am using `rails` 3.0.20 and `cucumber-rails` 1.3.1.

After trying a few things, I tried this:

```
rails generate cucumber:install
```

That solved it for me.